# Ray tracing: Ellipsoid Hit function

Tags: c++, visualization, simulation, modeling, raytracing

We are working with shape generation using ray tracing. We believe that the hit function is not working appropriately. Currently, the "front" side of the ellipsoid is lit correctly. As the shape rotates, it has problems reflecting light. [Example of rotating the ellipsoid.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ZI4W.gif)

Below is the current version of the Hit function.

```
bool Ellipsoid::Hit(const Ray& ray,
                 const double minHitDistance,
                 const double maxHitDistance,
                 HitRecord& hitRecord,
                 const Vector3d& light) const {

    if (hitRecord.shapeHit == this) {
        return false;
    }

    // M is a 3x3 matrix 
    const Vector3d& direction = (M.inverse()*ray.Direction());
    const Vector3d oc = M.inverse()*(ray.Origin() -this->center);


    const double a = direction.dot(direction);

    const double b = oc.dot(direction);

    const double c = oc.dot(oc) - 1;

    const double discriminant = b*b - a*c;
    if (discriminant > 0) {

        const double sqrtDiscriminant = sqrt(discriminant);
        const double aReciprocal = 1.0 / a;  
        double temp = (-b - sqrtDiscriminant) * aReciprocal;
        if (temp < maxHitDistance && temp > minHitDistance) {
            hitRecord.distance = temp;
            hitRecord.closestIntersection = ray.PointAtParameter(hitRecord.distance);

            hitRecord.normal = M.inverse()*((hitRecord.closestIntersection - center) / 1);
            hitRecord.shapeHit = this;
            return true;
        }
        temp = (-b + sqrtDiscriminant) * aReciprocal;
        if (temp < maxHitDistance && temp > minHitDistance) {
            hitRecord.distance = temp;
            hitRecord.closestIntersection = ray.PointAtParameter(hitRecord.distance);

            hitRecord.normal =      M.inverse()*((hitRecord.closestIntersection - center) / 1);
            hitRecord.shapeHit = this;
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

The first thing we tried was changing M.transpose() to M.inverse() on the lines where we set hitRecord.normal. This made the light look significantly better but did not completely help the light accuracy after rotating the object. We are unsure if the Hit function is completely correct. We just need some guidance to see if we need to look for other faults in the program. Any advice helps.

Edit: We have tried modifying the discriminant as well. This causes the function to break because the "4" is accounted for throughout the function (as seen in comment section).

Comment: Any chance you used another local variable called `center` somewhere? If so then in the line `hitRecord.normal =  M.inverse()*((hitRecord.closestIntersection - center) / 1);` you might have used the wrong `center` instead of `this->center`

Comment: `b*b - a*c`? Maybe `b*b-4*a*c`?

Comment: Dave, I forgot to mention we had tried this approach before and it causes the hit to fail. The way the function is designed accounts for that 4 elsewhere.

Comment: Michael, we will try this approach. Thank you.

Comment: Glad you got it fixed. But, if you're accounting for the 4 elsewhere, you'd still need to modify your `if (discriminant > 0)` here. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

After completely rewriting the function, we have determined the issue does not lie within the hit function.